# Sharepoint Online Calendar to Outlook Sync Issues

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to display all events that appear on SharePoint calendar on Outlook by using the Connect to Outlook option on SharePoint, but after syncing the calendar on Outlook the event descriptions are all blank as shown below:

[image]

Can someone please check and help me with what might be causing this sync issue when I try to connect to Outlook from Sharepoint? The event descriptions are appearing correctly in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that event descriptions are not shown in the outlook like below? As per my test, only event titles can be shown in Outlook. I'm afraid it is by design.
[image]

Comment: I am not able to see the event title as well in outlook when the sync happens. Any idea what might be happening?